# How can I access an /etc/environment variable in PHP?

Tags: php, environment-variables

I can't seem to access any environmental variables set in /etc/environment via PHP. I have tried `$_ENV`, `$_SERVER` and `getenv()`.

I also checked the output of `phpinfo()` to attempt to list the environmental variables. They were not there, which would indicate the issue to be with Apache or the PHP configuration.

I am using PHP7.0 with Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.1, hosted on DigitalOcean. Hoping someone can help me.

Comment: Did you tell Apache to load said environmental variables?

Comment: if you told us which specific variable you wanted, it would help

Comment: @nogad: I set one myself via SSH using the `export` command -- the name is `DB_NAME`.

Comment: if you want variables for php scripts, that's not the usual approach

Comment: @Machavity: Yes, I have per the answer to the duplicate you marked this question with. No success.

Comment: It's not, @nogad, but I don't want to store database credentials in source control for obvious reasons.

Comment: honestly, its not obvious, because we all do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122240/discussion-between-connor-gurney-and-nogad).

Comment: I'm adding comment here to make this Q self-contained: in php.ini, ensure `variables_order = "EGPCS"` (notice the E, for environment).